# SQL data returned on 2 lines instead of 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to make my query return the desired data all on 1 line. It does return all the desired data, but on 2 seperate lines.

The full query is below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
   case when sh1.Comments = 'clermont-0041 (Depot)'  
             then CAST(sh1.ScanTime as VARCHAR)  
        else ' '  
   end as 'Pickup Scan Time',  
   case when sh1.Comments = 'clermont-0041 (Depot)'  
             then sh1.Comments  
        else ' '  
   end as 'Pickup Scan',  
  case when sh1.Comments = 'orlwarehouse01-0041 (Depot)'  
            then CAST(sh1.ScanTime as VARCHAR)  
       else ' '  
  end as 'Warehouse Scan Time',  
  case when sh1.Comments = 'orlwarehouse01-0041 (Depot)'  
            then sh1.Comments  
       else ' '  
  end as 'Warehouse Scan',  
sh1.MasterScanID
FROM 
   tblOrder o  
   join tblScanHistory sh1 on o.OrderID = sh1.MasterScanID  
   join tblOrder on sh1.MasterScanID = o.OrderID
WHERE  
   (sh1.Comments = 'clermont-0041 (Depot)'
   or sh1.Comments = 'orlwarehouse01-0041 (Depot)')  
   and sh1.MasterScanID IS NOT NULL  
   and sh1.Scan like 'X-0041-D%'  
   and o.OrderID = '4419250'
ORDER BY
   sh1.MasterScanID desc
```

**The result set looks like this:**

```
Pickup Scan Time    | Pickup Scan           | Warehouse Scan Time | Warehouse Scan              | MasterScanID
                    |                       | May  2 2017 12:01AM | orlwarehouse01-0041 (Depot) | 4419250.00 
May  1 2017 12:32PM | clermont-0041 (Depot) |                     |                             | 4419250.00
```

Comment: Looks like your first 2 case statements are resulting in the else clause for the first row, and visa versa for the second. How about some sample data?

Comment: Why do you need the join to order twice?

Answer (score 2):

Using `group by` and `max()` to aggregate your data:

```
select 
    o.OrderID
  , [Pickup Scan Time] = max(case 
      when sh1.Comments = 'clermont-0041 (Depot)' 
        then convert(varchar(23),sh1.ScanTime,121) 
      end)
  , [Pickup Scan] =  max(case 
      when sh1.Comments = 'clermont-0041 (Depot)' 
        then sh1.Comments
      end)
  , [Warehouse Scan Time] = max(case 
      when sh1.Comments = 'orlwarehouse01-0041 (Depot)'
        then convert(varchar(23),sh1.ScanTime,121) 
      end)
  , [Warehouse Scan] = max(case 
      when sh1.Comments = 'orlwarehouse01-0041 (Depot)'
        then sh1.Comments
      end)
from tblOrder o  
  left join tblScanHistory sh1 
    on o.OrderID = sh1.MasterScanid
   and sh1.Scan like 'X-0041-D%'
   and sh1.Comments in ('clermont-0041 (Depot)','orlwarehouse01-0041 (Depot)')
where o.OrderID = '4419250'
group by o.OrderID 
order by o.OrderID desc
```

Also, it would be best to specify your aliases with square brackets instead of single quotes, as they are identifiers, not string literals.

Other note:

[Bad habits to kick : declaring `varchar` without (length) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should always provide a length for all `varchar` or `nvarchar` variables/parameters.

Comment: Sorry SqZim, but I spoke too soon. Using 'MAX' only returns the top result. This query should return hundreds of lines.

Comment: I still don't know why your first query doesn't work though...  the group by on the scan id should cause all the other records to appear... ah perhaps the inner joins are eliminating them?  function of the inner join/where not the max/group by?

Comment: I could always delete mine you have both covered and are still engaged :P and I was just trying to be different; not sure which is better from a maintenance/performance standpoint.  Though I'm a fan of joins and operating on sets when i can so i like the joins over the case;b ut not sure about performance.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be different... :P

You could join to scanhistory twice based on the comment you're looking for and eliminate the case statements.

To keep the order then move the limiting criteria on tblScanHistory to the joins and make the joins left joins.

```
SELECT  CAST(sh1.ScanTime as VARCHAR(25))  [Pickup Scan Time]
              ,  sh1.Comments  [Pickup Scan]
              ,  CAST(sh2.ScanTime as VARCHAR(25))  [Warehouse Scan Time]
              ,  sh2.Comments  [Warehouse Scan]
              ,  sh1.MasterScanID
FROM tblOrder o  
LEFT join tblScanHistory sh1 
  on o.OrderID = sh1.MasterScanID  
 AND sh1.Comments = 'clermont-0041 (Depot)'
 AND sh1.Scan like 'X-0041-D%'  
LEFT join tblScanHistory sh2 
  on o.OrderID = sh2.MasterScanID  
 AND sh2.Comments = 'orlwarehouse01-0041 (Depot)'
 AND sh2.Scan like 'X-0041-D%'  
WHERE o.OrderID = '4419250'
ORDER BY
   sh1.MasterScanID desc
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not getting good results out of either of these answers. I thought the first one worked, but using MAX, it only returns 1 result at a time and there is usually several hundred matching lines of data.

Comment: Also, when the scan data (the data in tblScanHistory) doesn't exist, nothing is returned. I would like the line to get returned, but minus the missing scan data.

Comment: Updated to left joins to keep order and only show history if it exists and moved limiting criteria on the tblScanHistory to the joins otherwise the left joins are treated like inner joins (the nulls generated by left join are eliminated by the where criteria)

Comment: I think the `distinct` might not be necessary.

Comment: OK, that worked great! I got all the data and everything looks perfect!
I REALLY appreciate your help! :-)

Comment: plus 1 for getting op to the solution -- though I still think the `distinct` is not necessary

Comment: Agree its not. Just left over from original